# What does the `directory-structure` tag refer to?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, tag-synonyms

I can't find some truly relevant correlation between questions tagged with [directory-structure](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/directory-structure), except maybe one.
Is this tag just a (poor) synonym for [fhs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fhs)? Or, is this some of kind of generalization to other usual layouts ? Would [directory-layouts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/directory-layouts) be a better naming?

Anyway, this tag deserves at least some short wiki-description.

Comment: FHS would be a subset of directory-structure, I think.

Comment: What's the difference between *structure* and *layout*, as related to directories?

Comment: "structure" makes me think of "*internal* structure" but maybe that's cause I answered a question about internal structure recently. Hmm, seems google is in favor of "directory structure".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The intended use of the [directory-structure](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/directory-structure) tag is for questions about the filesystem layout of unix systems — questions like “where does this file belong?” or “what is this directory for?”. At least, that's the use I intend, and seems to be mostly followed; I've just retagged a two of questions that used it in the sense of copying directories while retaining the structure, which we use [recursive](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recursive) for. [directory-layout](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/directory-layout) would be a reasonable synonym.

I've written a tag wiki for [directory-structure](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/directory-structure) and [recursive](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recursive), feel free to improve them.

Comment: +1 for the wiki, and the check mark for the clarifications.